# LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS in Neo4j with muliti-word headers

Tags: csv, neo4j

I am trying to load a csv file with multi word headers but I don't know how to access the field with multi-word header

```
"Timestamp","Username","Name","Gender","School Education"
"2017/02/14 4:12:48 PM GMT+5:30","gtg13@gmail.com","ran","Male","Yes"
"2017/02/14 4:13:10 PM GMT+5:30","sw.110@gmail.com","she","Female","No"
"2017/02/14 4:13:42 PM GMT+5:30","spj07@gmail.com","moaj","Male","No"
```

Here the multi-word header is "School Education"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use backtick like this

```
load csv with headers from "file:///Assessment2.csv" as line
return line.`School Education`
```